# Vista/7 UAC: how to lower process privileges

Tags: c#, uac, windows-vista, samba

Is it possible for a process to lower itself from elevated UAC permission back to standard user? If not can the elevated process launch its copy with standard user token and then kill itself? Any code examples (C# preferred)?

Details:

Problem:
- user installs my product (written in C#)
- the installer elevates its UAC permission to admin
- at the end the installer launches my exe
- the exe inherits elevated permissions from admin 
- the exe mounts network drives which become invisible in Windows Explorer (that runs with regular permissions)

Options I considered:
1) break installer into outer exe and inner exe, that runs with elevated permission. The install consists of 1000+ lines of NSIS code and I don't know anything about NSIS
2) mounting drives with lower permissions. If I do it Win Explorer can see the drives but my exe cannot
3) setting EnableLinkedConnection registry option to 1. This is a no-go because it requires PC reboot during the installation.

Please help!

Sergey

Comment: This probably belongs on serverfault.com or superuser.com

Comment: No. This is programming related.

Answer (score 3):

One way: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/VistaElevator.aspx

Another way (mentioned in most recent comment in previous article): http://brandonlive.com/2008/04/27/getting-the-shell-to-run-an-application-for-you-part-2-how/

Comment: I googled this issue back and forth, including codeproject.com, and somehow this article never came up. Just what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Personally, i prefer to remove "run this application" from my installer :) It may be inconvenient, but Windows Vista and Windows 7 provide a search box in Start menu so my application can be discovered easily.

Comment: I like this blog entry and the library he links to http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2009/07/09/launch-a-process-as-standard-user-from-an-elevated-process.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to get this working in all configurations, there are ugly hacks like [Kyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547732/vista-7-uac-how-to-lower-process-privileges/2547773#2547773) links to, but in the end, there is no real way to lower your rights. Since you mention NSIS, it so happens that it does have a plugin called [UAC](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/UAC_plug-in) that does the inner/outer instance dance, it's not pretty but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with a "hack" answer, another [blog post](http://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2013/01/nsis-lunch-program-as-user-from-uac.html) about NSIS shows a much simpler approach. Just using `explorer.exe` to launch another process *seems* to work.*

The C# would just be

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", YourProgram.ExecutablePath)
```

Beware that even if you `WaitForExit()` explorer, your program likely hasn't finished yet!

*Also beware one of the comments: "Unfortunately, the Windows Shell team has replied that the current behavior of "Explorer.exe AppName.exe" is a bug and may not work in future updates/versions of Windows. Applications should not rely upon it."