# How can I start-process without it inheriting admin rights?

Tags: powershell, admin-rights

I have a powershell instance that has admin rights.

In it I run the following command:

```
start-process MyProgram.exe
```

Powershell then tries to run MyProgram with admin privileges (because Powershell has them itself). I don't want this to happen, I want MyProgram to not have admin rights, as if I ran this command in a PowerShell instance without admin rights. How can I accomplish this?

---

#### Duplicate with [How to run exe with/without elevated privileges from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29266622/8527611)

However, I wasn't able to find a solution over there which uses the `start-process` commandlet, which makes it more difficult / impossible to open a file with an .exe as `start-process MyProgram.exe -file MyFile.txt` would do.

Comment: Consider passing the argument `-Verb Open` to `Start-Process` or `-Verb RunAsUser`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29266622/how-to-run-exe-with-without-elevated-privileges-from-powershell

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 , `-Verb Open` does not appear to change the behaviour, `-Verb RunAsUser` gives me a log in prompt, without even suggesting my currently logged in profile, so this isn't an ideal solution either, but entering my log in details did give me a program without admin privileges.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run exe with/without elevated privileges from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29266622/how-to-run-exe-with-without-elevated-privileges-from-powershell)

Comment: To be clear: You DO want the full instance of the PowerShell call to utilize administrative rights, but specifically NOT when it instantiates a line (or other code) such as `Start-Process`?  If not, why not instantiate the PowerShell script fully as the non-elevated user?

Comment: @gravitymixes , well, I open the shell by default with admin rights, just so I don't have to worry about which type of shell I have open. But any other program I open with it (for example downloaded software etc.) I don't want to give these admin rights as well. So that would indeed mean that the `start-process` would run in admin mode, but just the opened process not. I would like to be able to type something in my shell to open some program (and give it normal rights), and I prefer to have my shell have admin rights. But I guess that's just not the designed workflow of Windows.

Comment: @Bassie-c Then the marked duplicate is, in fact, exactly your answer.