# Launch application with less permissions than "Run As Admin"

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, permissions

I have an application which needs to run As Admin. - no problems with this.

This app sometimes needs to launch a secondary application, however this second application inherits the "Run as Admin" elevated status from the parent application. I don't want this, I would like to launch the second application with the same rights as would be granted when not launching "As Admin"

I can find many articles for this scenario the other way round, but none for lowering access rights.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/869c3d36-87cb-4d9b-8ba3-13d620f49b9e/starting-a-process-with-lower-privileges?forum=csharpgeneral) redirected me to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870319/c-sharp-starting-process-with-lowered-privileges-from-uac-admin-level-process)

It proposes the following since starting a non-elevated process from an elevate is error-prone:

> 1. Your app initially starts as non-elevated application, and its manifest has `asInvoker` level.
> 2. When it starts, it restarts itself with elevated privileges using `runas` verb, and passes a command-line parameter to indicate it. This instance performs all parts that need admin priviledges.
> 3. Here comes the non-elevated app again, and starts your secondary application with the same non-elevated user token that started the first instance of the app in step 1.

I hope this can anyhow be applied to your scenario.

As said, what you want to achieve is very error-prone, yet [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547732/vista-7-uac-how-to-lower-process-privileges) there are some possible hacky solutions.

Comment: thanks. you lead me down the rabbit hole too: 
http://mdb-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/nsis-lunch-program-as-user-from-uac.html

Comment: Thanks for the blog link, interesting approach. Glad I could help.